# Why do we have the prefix "be" in "befriend"? What's the rule?

Tags: verbs, prefixes

What is the verb form of the noun *friend*?

I know it is *to befriend*, but I am confused as to how to teach this to my daughter.

When is the prefix *be* used to make verbs? Is "befriend" an exception?

Comment: I don't think there are reliable general rules...

Comment: Depends a bit on how old your daughter is. But I would be careful with "rules" about word formation for young learners. The possibilites with prefixes, suffixes, compound elements and cero conversion are considerable and there is no system in it. Systematic word formation you will only find in Esperanto.

Comment: People will tell you the answer, if you "friend" them first.

Comment: Wiktionary, on **be-** "8 *(rare or no longer productive) Forming verbs derived from nouns or adjectives, usually with the sense of "to make, become, or cause to be." **becalm, bedark, befree, befriend, bedim, beken, benight, benothing, bewet, besmooth**" Today, we no longer form new words with the *be-* prefix in this sense. HTH.

Comment: Entertain the little one with this: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-words-with-the-most-whimsical-prefix/

Answer (score 2):

*Befriend* is an actual verb that is linked in meaning to the noun *friend*.

There are more such pairs, and sometimes one can be formed from the other. There may be *some* patterns, but I would indeed not go looking for rules. Semantically linked pairs or triplets of nouns, verbs and adjectives have been used throughout history, and they have been borrowed from one language to another, sometimes as a set, sometimes individually.

A favourite example of mine is that an *undertaking* is not linked semantically to an *undertaker* in English. Since that word was used already for someone who buries people, the French *entrepreneur* was borrowed. *Entrepreneurship* was then formed on English rules, and borrowed back into French.

If no verb exists yet for a noun, people sometimes use the noun *unchanged* as a verb. In some cases, those “verbed nouns” actually catch on, but usually they are a one-of. But someone who adds a point to a meeting agenda can be said to *table* an issue. The (proper) noun *Google* is now also used as a verb.

It can be very interesting to try and find *patterns* in word-formation, but rogermue mentions in their comment, beware of defining “rules” for it. Generations of language users have shown an incredible creativity in forming words, and just about *any* “rule” you find will likely have more exceptions than words that follow it.

The noun *friend* is actually a nice example, because the verb *befriend* has been around for some time, but when (FaceBook, wasn't it) was looking for a verb with the opposite meaning, they coined *unfriend*, which looks like it is based on a verb *friend*.